# How can I add user input parameter as a column value of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add user input parameter in gridview

```
Calling frequency   Unique Caller   No of Call
    15                  7               116
    B/n 14-11           11              133
    B/n 10-8            50              412
    B/n 7-2             8528            20635
    One Times           46219           46219
    Total               54815           67515
```

its possible to display the second and the third column due to its from the database.

How can i display the first column in the gridview ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes

The GridViewSearch control is an ASP.NET user control that provides search/filtering capabilities which can then be used to filter a DataTable/DataSource bound to a GridView control. There are two search modes available in the control: Basic and Advanced. Both modes construct a SQL-based WHERE-clause filter, which can be later set to a DataView's RowFilter property.

For details see http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/GridViewSearch.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, but what i need is, if you see just above there are three columns. the second and the third is retrieved from the database due to it is a report. my question is <<the first column is user input>> then how can i display it in the grid view by appending with the report.

Comment: You have to put textbox inside a gridview for first column and when you run this first time its textbox empty and when the user put the value hare then you can fire txtbox click event../

Comment: check this http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/bind-data-to-textbox-in-inside-of.html link

Comment: and also you have to download the code and see that how would be work in this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Comment: Dear, thank you  again but what i need and your answer is not match what i need is in second and third columns are display from Database using Grid view and in first column the data is from user/parameter so, how can i bind them . please would you help me by giving Source code.

Comment: iI have only give the idea that how to use this code and apply on you code not the coreect those which you want i think you undersand that what i say so please check http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource14-Dropdown-checkbox-and-textbox-controls-in-aspnet-editable-Gridview.aspx   download the code and work on that

Comment: Hello Experts is there any body who can help me?